# How to save results as csv and manage the columns? (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I have tried using import pandas as pd and am able to produce a csv but it is not how I want it to be. I want it to be saved/printed across the columns rather than down as rows (so job title as the header for column 'A' and all the results listed in the rows etc...

This is my code, what do I need to change to flip the results to appear the other way with all my results.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import re
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://company.onefootball.com/jobs/#jobs-wrap'
departmentcategories = {
    "android": "Software Development",
    "social media": "Marketing",
    "content ": "Marketing",
    "sales": "Sales",
}

languagecategories = {
    " and ": "English",
    " und ": "German",
}

experiencecategories = {
    "senior": "Mid Senior Level",
    "Junior": "Entry Level",
}

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)

r.html.render(sleep=1)

jobs = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="jobs-wrap"]', first=True)

def get_department_categories(department):
    depcats = []
    for k, v in departmentcategories.items():
        if re.search(k, department, re.IGNORECASE):
            depcats.append(v)
    return depcats
 
def get_language_categories(language):
    langcats = []
    for k, v in languagecategories.items():
        if re.search(k, language, re.IGNORECASE):
            langcats.append(v)
    return langcats 

def get_experience_categories(experience):
    expcats = []
    for k, v in experiencecategories.items():
        if re.search(k, experience, re.IGNORECASE):
            expcats.append(v)
    return expcats 

for item in jobs.absolute_links:
    r = s.get(item)
    job_title = r.html.find('h1.headline', first=True).text
    city = r.html.find('p.h6', first=True).text    

    if city == ('Berlin, Germany'):
        city = 'Berlin'
        
    country = r.html.find('p.h6', first=True).text

    if country == ('Berlin, Germany'):
        country = 'Germany'
    
    #Section for the department, languages, and experience level

    department = r.html.find('div.job-content--parsed', first=True).text
    department_cats = get_department_categories(department)

    language = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="job"]/div[1]/div[2]', first=True).text
    language_cats = get_language_categories(language)

    experience = r.html.find('div.job-content--parsed', first=True).text
    experience_cats = get_experience_categories(experience)
    
joblist = [job_title, city, country, "OneFootball", ", ".join(department_cats), ", ".join(experience_cats), ", ".join(language_cats), "Sport", item]

df = pd.DataFrame(joblist)

print(df.head())

df.to_csv('newtest.csv')
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand: Why don't you just transpose the frame (`df = df.T`)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob to python and coding in general. How would I edit the df to include the .T as well as the dataframe, because I tried df=pd.DataFrame.T(joblist) but it didn't work?

Comment: That would be `df = pd.DataFrame(joblist).T`.

Comment: Great that solved the issue with it showing rows instead of as columns, but there is still the problem that it only gives me one line of results rather than the whole rows of data scraped

Comment: Any one have an idea of how I can save all my results to csv rather than just one row? thanks in advance